# Export a numpy matrix of complex numbers to CSV

Tags: python, matlab, csv, numpy, complex-numbers

I am having the following trouble in Python. Assume a `numpy.matrix` A with entities of `dtype` to be `complex128`. I want to export A in CSV format so that the entries are separated by commas and each line at the output file corresponds to a row of A. I also need 18 decimal points of precision for both the real and imaginary parts and no spaces within an entry for example I need this

```
`6.103515626000000000e+09+1.712134684679831166e+05j`
```

instead of

```
`6.103515626000000000e+09 + 1.712134684679831166e+05j`
```

The following command works but only for 1-by-1 matrix

```
numpy.savetxt('A.out', A, fmt='%.18e%+.18ej', delimiter=',')
```

If I use:

```
numpy.savetxt('A.out', A, delimiter=',')
```

there are two problems. First, I don't know how many decimal points are preserved by default. Second, each complex entry is put in parentheses like

`(6.103515626000000000e+09+1.712134684679831166e+05j)`

and I cannot read the file in Matlab.

What do you suggest?

Comment: It's docs lists possible complex formats.  This `fmt=['%.18e+%.18ej']*5` works for a 5 column array.  In other words when you specify both the real and imag parts you have specify the format for all columns.  It won't do replication for you.  If that doesn't help, you may need to read the `savetxt` code, paying attention to how it treats complex arrays.

Comment: The format for a single row is effectively: `','.join(['%.18e+%.18ej']*5)%tuple(x[0].view(float))`.  That is it formats a tuple of the complex values separated into 2 floats.  So one way or other there has to be a format string for each of  `A.shape[1]*2` values.

Comment: @hpaulj I have tried your suggestion and it works. The problem I am facing now is that it prints `+-` for numbers with negative imaginary part like `1.000000000000000000e+00+-6.103515625000000000e+09j` which cannot be read by Matlab. Is there any workaround?

Comment: `genfromtxt` can't load that format either.  Maybe we need to look at the Python `%` formatting options.  Really all `savetxt` is doing is iterating on rows, and formatting each as a text line.  So anything you can do to get a pretty `print` line should also work when writing to a text file.

Comment: If the target is MATLAB, you could try `scipy.io.savemat`, creating a `.mat` compatible file, instead of a text.

Comment: We just need to move the `+` inside the `%` expression, e.g. `['%.18e%+.18ej']`, so it displays `+/-` with the imag part.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-bytes-formatting.  See also the `savetxt` docs under `notes/flags`.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks, you saved my day. The manual looks quite perplexed to me. But can you give me the link where you found the possible complex formats you described in your first comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably not the most efficient way of converting data in the large matrix and I am sure there exists a more efficient one-line-of-code solution, but you can try executing the code below and see if it works. Here I will be using pandas to save data to a csv file. The first columns in the generated csv file would be respectively your real and imaginary parts. Here I also assume that the dimension of the input matrix is Nx1.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def to_csv(t, nr_of_decimal = 18):
    t_new = np.matrix(np.zeros((t.shape[0], 2)))
    t_new[:,:] = np.round(np.array(((str(np.array(t[:])[0][0])[1:-2]).split('+')), dtype=float), decimals=nr_of_decimal)
    (pd.DataFrame(t_new)).to_csv('out.csv', index = False, header = False)

#Assume t is your complex matrix
t = np.matrix([[6.103515626000000000e+09+1.712134684679831166e+05j], [6.103515626000000000e+09+1.712134684679831166e+05j]])    
to_csv(t)
```